# Codewars 'odd or even?' on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Task:
Given a list of numbers, determine whether the sum of its elements is odd or even.

Give your answer as a string matching "odd" or "even".

If the input array is empty consider it as: [0] (array with a zero).
My code:

```
 function oddOrEven(array) {
  return array.reduce( function (sum, item) { return sum + item }) % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
}
```

My problem:
Passed: 14 Failed: 1 Errors: 1 Exit Code: 1
TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
Why?

Comment: Seems like the array was empty and reduce can't handle empty arrays

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my problem was that i didn't make an initialValue like '0'
My answer:

`function oddOrEven(array) {
return array.reduce( function (sum, item) { return sum + item }, 0) % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an initial value for the reduce accumulator. `reduce(accFunc, initialAccValue)`, like this:

```js
function oddOrEven(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(sum, item) {
    return sum + item
  }, 0) % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
}

console.log(oddOrEven([1, 2]));
console.log(oddOrEven([1, 3]));
console.log(oddOrEven([]));
```

Comment: @MaximFedotov please feel free to accept the answer. That way other users will see that the question has been answered.

Answer (score -1):

This is the sintax of the function reduce:

```
arr.reduce(callback(accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]]) [, initialValue])
```

In order to avoid this error, you need to specify the `initialValue`.

In your example should be `0`:

```
   function oddOrEven(array) {
      return array.reduce( function (sum, item) { return sum + item }, 0) % 2 == 0 ? 'even': 'odd';
    }
```

Check the documentation for [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score -2):

```
function oddOrEven(array) {
    var sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    return sum%2 == 0 || sum == 0 ? "even" : "odd";
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.